# mysqli_query returns number instead of varchar

Tags: php, mysqli

```
require 'connection.php';

if(isset($_POST['input'])){
    $input = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn ,$_POST['input']);

    $query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT 'Iloco' FROM ylokaknow.words WHERE English='$input'") or die(mysqli_error($conn));

print_r($query);

}
```

Instead of having a varchar on result I get a number

```
mysqli_result Object
(
    [current_field] => 0
    [field_count] => 1
    [lengths] => Array
      (
        [0]=> 5
      )

    [num_rows] => 1
    [type] => 0

)
```

The result should contain string or varchar. I don't know why it returns a 5 value. Please help.

Comment: `print_r(mysqli_fetch_assoc($query));`

Comment: now it does not return anything

Comment: @Steve it does not return anything sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `'` from `Iloco` column name.

Use this.

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT Iloco FROM ylokaknow.words WHERE English='$input'") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

**On User Demand.**

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT Iloco FROM words WHERE English='$input'") or die(mysqli_error($conn)); 
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC); 
echo $Iloco = $row['Iloco'];
```

Comment: same problem. can you advice a code where I can fetch single data from database and convert it to string? so I can display it in my web.

Comment: First of all, `words` in your table name. Ok. ? Why don't u use like this `SELECT Iloco FROM words WHERE English='$input'` and check @MarkKleinFermin

Comment: And, you are pretty sure about column name. Means, column name are case sensitive. Are you using the same column name as in table.? Just asking @MarkKleinFermin

Comment: `echo "SELECT Iloco FROM words WHERE English='$input'";` and paste the result in your sql of php my admin. And, see what error coming @MarkKleinFermin

Comment: no error it returns the correct varchar. how can i post the screen shot here?

Comment: edit in your question with screen shot @MarkKleinFermin

Comment: Glad you found. By the way what was the problem @MarkKleinFermin ?

Comment: your solution SELECT Iloco FROM words WHERE English='$input' is correct. and I put this code $queValue = mysqli_fetch_object($querry); and print it it returns my varchar. but my problem is how will I convert this into string

Comment: Happy. :) Varchar is string. @MarkKleinFermin Enjoy Coding.

Comment: I mean it returns the varchar. with in object.

Comment: `$query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT Iloco FROM words WHERE English='$input'") or die(mysqli_error($conn));

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

echo $Iloco = $row['Iloco'];` Do Like this @MarkKleinFermin

Comment: Always Welcome @MarkKleinFermin. Feel Free To Ask In SO. Regards From India.